# Sum of an Infinite Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> If $$ S = \frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 5 \cdot 7} +
>   \frac{1}{5\cdot 7 \cdot 9} \cdots  $$
>
> $$S =\, ? $$

***My Attempt***

Let the general term be $ a_n $.

Then, $$ a_n = \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)} $$

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{(2n+3)-(2n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)} \right]$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{∞}a_n = \frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{1}{1\cdot3} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}\right]$$

*As n $\to$ ∞*, 
 $$ \sum_{n=1}^{∞}a_n = \frac{1}{12}$$

Is this the correct?

Comment: Should that $8$ be a $9$?

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: and usual notation is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: I guess you want $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N$$

Comment: They also asked to find [36S] where ' [ . ] ' stands for greatest integer function. Is it 3? But it is given 2 in my book. Did they consider, $$ \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)} ≠ 0$$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No. It was my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Better to say $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n=\dfrac1{12}$$

Comment: Seems correct. I'd write: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k = \frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{1}{1\cdot3} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}\right]$$ instead of $$\sum_{n=1}^{∞}a_n = \frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{1}{1\cdot3} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}\right]$$ which is incorrect notation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. But how will i represent $ n \to ∞ $. Should I use $$ \lim_{n\to∞} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right but more methodically:

For the series $$T_n=\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}$$
Let $$V_n=\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)},$$ then $$T_n=\frac{1}{4}[V_{n}-V_{n+1}].$$ By telescopic summing we get $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}=\frac{1}{4} [V_1-V_{N+1}]=\frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{1}{1.3}-\frac{1}{(2N+1)(2N+3)}\right].$$ Hence $$S_{\infty}=\frac{1}{12}.$$

Comment: Isn't this the same as my solution?

Comment: @Kaushik yes, see the top lime of my Answer.